# I am confused about between using typescript or Javascript with Protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, browser-automation

Our Team is starting a new Functional Test Automation Project for newly Developed Angular App. 
Can you please suggest what would be a better choice in long run with Protractor (type script vs Java script)
Will google keep on supporting Java Script API for new protractor versions.

Comment: What research indicates Protractor 'will stop supporting JavaScript'? Protractor is built largely *for* AngularJS, so until AngularJS 'stops supporting JavaScript', Protractor really can't 'stop supporting JavaScript'. Largely, it comes down to which language (remember: TypeScript "compiles into" JavaScript-really-ECMAScript) the team/organization wishes to promote/use..

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript that brings users optional static types and solid tooling. Using TypeScript can help avoid painful bugs people commonly run into when writing JavaScript by type-checking your code. TypeScript can actually report issues without you even saving your file, and leverage the type system to help you write code even faster. This leads to a truly awesome editing experience, giving you time to think about and test the things that really matter.
According to this TypeScript can offer more.

Answer (score 1):

First understand Protractor runs only a Javascript file(JS).

Even if you use Typescript(TS).You have to first compile it to JS using typescript compiler and then only you can run it with protractor.

Using TS or JS is of your own interest.